# How long should I wait for a response to my request for a reference letter from my former employer?

Tags: human-resources, employer-relations, references

I needed a reference letter from my former employer for my immigration case. So I asked the person responsible for HR & he told me to fill in the appropriate details in the interest of speeding up the process & send it back to him.

Great, so my lawyer & his team drafted one that would conform to specifications that the immigration department needs.

I send that to him on Monday & waited for almost a day & when there was no response back from him, I called him & he told me that I would get it by the end of this week.

It's Friday now & I haven't heard back from him yet. I emailed him today asking him for an update and copied my lawyer & his team as well. But it has been an hour since that email & I am contemplating writing to the CTO who's the co-owner as well to have that processed as soon as possible. My lawyer has specifically told me that without the reference letter, my case has the higher chances of getting rejected, so naturally this is the most important thing.

What should I do here?

Comment: When do you need the letter by? If you are in a rush, a phone call is always better than an email.

Comment: I have like one and a half month left actually but sooner I am able to get in my application with immigration department, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you call your former employer and politely express the urgency of your need.  You cannot push to hard though, as they do not **have** to do anything for you.

Sometimes a polite phone call can go a lot further than an email in conveying your message.  Sometimes people skim over emails and the urgency of a request is lost.

If you have to leave a voice mail, try something like this:

Hello WHOEVER, this is WHOEVER calling to check on the letter of reference I sent to you. I was hoping you have the time to take care of this as soon possible, as I **really need it** by WHATEVERDATE. ( *emphasizing really need it* )  Without this letter, **my case will be incomplete** and I may not get the job.  Thanks for your help in this matter.

Comment: Here's the thing, the person I am calling doesn't usually answer my calls on first try.

Comment: The tone of your voice in a voice mail can help you convey urgency.  Not suggesting you beg or any such thing, but you could say you really need it quickly with the proper emphasis.

Comment: One thing I am bad at is phrasing my words carefully. What should be the proper message here?

Comment: Should I mention the incompleteness of my case without their letter?

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at my updated answer.